# Indicator light burning on keyboard with no known reason

Tags: drivers, keyboard, 15.10

The mic indicator light is burning without a reason. It suddenly started after I restarted my computer. 
How can I turn it off again?

- Laptop: HP probook 650
- Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 15.10
- Desktop environement: Gnome 3.x

**OUPUT**:`ls -l /sys/class/led`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  7 16:36 hp::hddprotect -> ../../devices/virtual/leds/hp::hddprotect
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  7 16:36 input3::capslock -> ../../devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::capslock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  7 16:36 input3::numlock -> ../../devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::numlock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  7 16:36 input3::scrolllock -> ../../devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/input3::scrolllock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar  7 16:36 phy0-led -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:03:00.0/leds/phy0-led
```

**NOTE:**
I tried turning each of these devices off with the command:
`echo 0 > brightness` in the respective folders. None of them turned out to be the burning led on my keyboard.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls /sys/class/leds`.

Comment: @ByteCommander I added the output but if i try to turn them off by doing `echo 0 > brightness` in the right directory,  I succeed in turning them off but non of them is the right led.